# How to get ion-input type date to open calendar when on desktop/core

Tags: angular, date, ionic-framework, input, ionic3

I have an ionic3/angular application that is also used on desktop/core. I have the typical...

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label></ion-label>
    <ion-datetime *ngIf="!platform.is('core')"></ion-datetime> //this line works just fine
    <ion-input type="date" *ngIf="platform.is('core')"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

for the user to enter a date (birthdate, enrollment date, etc.). My problem is that ion-input doesn't seem to support type 'date.' It seems to be defaulting to some sort of text input. Setting it up as above DOES allow me to manually edit the day/month/year inputs as well as use a master set of up/down arrows on the right to also adjust the inputs, but it doesn't open up the calendar as a typical html input type date would seemingly do.

Here are all of the alternatives/things I have tried so far...

- ion-input type="date" (doesn't work for reasons mentioned above)
- ion-datetime element (I would rather have the popup calendar for desktop view rather than the scrollodex as on mobile)
- ionic native datepicker (obviously doesn't work outside of Cordova)
- input type="date" (doesn't even register as a clickable input inside of ion-item)

So essentially my problem is that I have an ionic application that is running cross platform with ion-datetime elements (which work perfectly for anything BUT desktop) but no way of opening up a calendar on some sort of input if the user is running the application on their desktop. Hopefully that makes sense. I've run into quite a few other stack questions that seem similar but not quite my particular dilemma. Thanks for any help!

Comment: How did you made this work? Can you edit or provide an answer with your approach?

Comment: We actually ended up just building our own calendar component that would work in both mobile and desktop. A lot more work initially but way more rewarding in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ion-datetime does not have support for a calendar. I suggest you use the platform service and ngIf your calendar of choice based on mobile or not.